# Django, serving static files with default settings

Tags: python, django

I'm writing an app using the Django Python web framework. I added my apps to the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and my templates are served without problems. But, concerning the static files, i have a little problem with them. I wanted to use the default parameters in STATICFILES_FINDER :

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

When i want to include a css file for example, in my template i just do (supposing '/' will be my static/applicationName in my application folder) :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="/css/style.css">
```

Am i doing it wrong, and if so, what's the good way to deal with static files ?

UPDATE :
My base.html template :

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
            <meta charset='utf-8'>       
            <title> {% block title %} {% endblock %} - Find Something </title>
            <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static  'css/style.css' %}">            
        {% endblock head %}        
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

And my inheriting template is :

```
{% extends "frontend/base.html" %}

{% block title %} {{ title }} {% endblock %}
{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Did you hook into your urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 {% static %}
 <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">

 {% block head %}
     {{block.super}}
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But there is something weird. All the templates inheriting of this one, don't work when i code something after the : {% extends "frontend/base.html" %} line. And the super() block gives me an error : Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'super()'

Comment: why frontend/base.html? In your templates you create frontend folder then you put base.html there?

Comment: Yes, my app tree is : templates/appName/templates ... and static/appName/{css,js,img}

Comment: Thanks ! It works, now. I've always used the super() syntax. (It's the one specified in the doc)

Comment: Can you give me the link for that docs? maybe it's the latest version

Comment: It's this one http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#template-inheritance (or maybe i'm checking the wrong doc)

Comment: Those are for Jinja templates not django templates. If you want to inherit that block, just don't add the `{% block %}` tags in the child page, they will be used from the parent automatically. From the django docs: `Note that since the child template didn’t define the sidebar block, the value from the parent template is used instead. Content within a {% block %} tag in a parent template is always used as a fallback.` Try these [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) for django templates